# Nested SVG overlap programmatic challenge

Tags: svg

I have a challenge before me and unfortunately I tend to suck at visual things.  I need to take two separate SVG images, from a pool of such images from two separate vendors, each possibly with their own coordinate systems, and combine them in the following way.  I have some things I can count on:

1. Each image from both vendors is square.
2. Vendor A's images are monochrome.
3. All images render nicely in a browser.
4. I've paid for licenses to both sets of images and per the terms I don't need to worry about attribution.
5. I can access the source to all SVG files.
6. I can manipulate the files more or less however I want to using groovy, if I can figure out the magic pattern.

I need to apply the following rules in my little self-imposed process:

1. Lay down an outline SVG frame that expects to render in a space 48 x 48.
2. Insert the chosen SVG image from the Vendor A set.
3. Apply a uniform color change to a chosen preselected color on that image.
4. Insert the chosen image from the Vendor B, and scale and position it such that it occupies the lower left quadrant. It should lay on top of the underlying Vendor A image. Its colors will remain untouched.
5. The whole thing should be renderable in J. Random Modern Browser.

So far I can't really seem to figure out the right pattern of nested SVGs, and most online tutorials give examples that don't even render in any of the free online svg editors.  I'm stuck and unsure how even to begin. Ordinarily I'd put some sample code in one of these questions, but at the moment none of them seem to come even close to working.

Vendor A icons look something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<g>
    <g transform="translate(50 50) scale(0.69 0.69) rotate(0) translate(-50 -50)" style="fill:#0059B3">
        <svg fill="#0059B3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
            <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </svg>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Vendor B icons look something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

I need to combine the two such that the second one sits on top of the LOWER LEFT quadrant of the first.  And the first needs to have a color change applied without altering the inner svg text, if that's possible.  It's beyond my abilities in Microsoft Paint to show that but I hope that's clear.

Comment: We really need a [mcve] here.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  If I had an example, minimal or complete or verifiable or otherwise, I wouldn't have raised the question.  I have no idea how to accomplish this, and hence I'm asking the community.

Comment: An example of the problem (two cut down example SVG files) and at least a picture of what the two images should look like when combined. You have that, no?

Comment: I don't think that I do.  As far as I can tell from a licensing perspective, I can't post these icons here.  And no, I can't show what the pictures should look like when combined -- I am completely hopeless with visual tools.  On the other hand I took great pains to describe the effect I am trying to achieve in my description of the problem.

Comment: two **cut down** example SVG files. Replace the real contents with a rect element or a circle or something that illustrates the issue.

Comment: You take your SVG images, and transform them in symbols. Is important to keep the viewBox attribute of the original SVG files as viewBox of the symbols. Next use the symbols as you like.

Comment: I will try ... but I don't think you realize how hard this is for me.  I once employed an engineer who was completely blind from a very young age.  He was better at visual tools than I am.  Are the words not sufficient to describe the issue?

Comment: @enxaneta, I think I'm getting that the viewBox is the crucial bit.  My intent is to keep the existing SVG text completely as-is, including the viewBox.  It's the "as you like" part that I'm lost at.

Comment: I would need to see some code in order to be able to tell you more. *Please* add a simplified version of your code.

Comment: I have done what I can.  If my intent is still not clear, I'll just delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've told you in my comment you need to transform your SVG in `<symbol>` elements and you `<use>` those `<symbol>`s. When you are using a `<symbol>` that has a `viewBox` attribute you can resize and reposition the shapes inside with the `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` attributes of the `<use>` element. In order to be able to change colors you move the styles in the `<use>` elements. Also you may opt for presentational attributes instead of css.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<defs>     
<symbol id="A" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<g>
    <g transform="translate(50 50) scale(0.69 0.69) rotate(0) translate(-50 -50)" >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
            <rect width="100" height="100"  />
        </svg>
    </g>
</g>
</symbol>

<symbol  id="B" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100" height="100"  />
</symbol>
</defs> 

  <use xlink:href="#B" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" x="5" y="5" width="90" height="90"/>
  <use  width="40" height="40" x="50" y="50" xlink:href="#B" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This gets me closer but with some tweaking (for example, I need to use the original svg whole and entire, and also you didn't reference #A) the solution still isn't quite there.  My "minimal verifiable etc" example isn't quite capturing what's happening when I put my full icons in place; the "B" icon I picked at random is getting chopped off.  I can solve that by making my symbol B viewBox arbitrarily large (but not too large).  I just can't quite figure out programmatically how to tell exactly _how_ large.  I'll amend my question to reflect this.

Comment: Y hope you have now a starting point and you'll be able to ask a better question

Comment: I believe I do, thanks to you!  New question coming shortly.